# Asynchronous Web Service Call From WPF Application

Tags: asp.net, web-services, asynchronous

I know a lot of people have posted for this, but I'm still having trouble matching the symptoms I have to what other people have encountered.  I created a simple web service in an empty asp.net website using Visual Studio 2010 (I just used the default web service with its Hello World implementation).  Then I created a WPF application and tried to call the web service from the application.  But I can't find the XXXAsync methods, or BeginXXX methods in the soap client proxy class using intellisense.  There's a method for calling HelloWorld synchronously, but nothing for asynchronous calls.  Is there something that I have to do in order to enable asynchronous support for a web service in asp.net?

Thanks,

Andrew

Comment: What about using WCF-services instead of web-services?

Comment: @vorrtex:  Thanks, I think you might be right.  I'm looking into that now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I think I figured out what I was doing wrong.  In Visual Studio 2010, I didn't mark the checkbox labeled "Generate asynchronous operations".  This can be found by:

1. right-clicking the name of the service in the solution explorer (which should be in the "Service References" folder".
2. going to "Configure Service Reference...".
3. Checking the box labeled "Generate asynchronous operations".

Hope this helps someone quicker than I was able to find it!

Andrew